# Restarting Kafka Streams Client on TopicAuthorizationException

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams client written in Scala that connects to a Kafka instance. Sometimes, during the initialization, I encounter a `TopicAuthorizationException`, for instance:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught during initialization of GlobalStreamThread
[error] org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught during initialization of GlobalStreamThread
[error]     at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.GlobalStreamThread.initialize(GlobalStreamThread.java:355)
[error]     at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.GlobalStreamThread.run(GlobalStreamThread.java:269)
[error] Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [first_topic]
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

This scenario is expected in my solution, and I need to handle it by pausing execution and restarting the client after a certain period of time. How can I properly handle this exception and implement the restart logic in my Kafka Streams client?

**Code Samples:**
Here is my build.sbt file:

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.18"

val kafkaVersion = "2.4.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "kafka-streams-playground"
  ).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % kafkaVersion,
  )
)
```

And my Kafka Streams client implementation:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
import org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{Consumed, Materialized}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Stores
import org.apache.kafka.streams.{KafkaStreams, StreamsConfig}

import java.util.Properties


object Main extends App {
  val props = new Properties

  props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "application_id")
  props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "state_dir")
  props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "http://localhost:9092")

  val topic = "first_topic"
  val storeName = topic

  val underlyingKVStore  = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName)

  implicit val consumed: Consumed[String, String] = Consumed.`with`(new StringSerde, new StringSerde)

  val streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
  streamsBuilder.globalTable[String, String](
    storeName,
    Materialized.as[String, String](underlyingKVStore)
  )

  val streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), props)
  streams.start()
}
```